# How to organize polymorphic ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, polymorphism, es6-modules

I have an application that has a bunch of globally scoped objects (essentially modules, but all at the window level). I'm trying to organize this a little better by moving to ES6 modules using imports and exports just where they're needed.

This all works fine except in cases where the objects use inheritance, where I don't want to explicitly import a specific device's version of a module.

The inheritance is set up to allow different behavior for different devices/environments by creating a bundle per device with Webpack. Each of the main bundle files imports all of the needed objects for that device.

For example, say I have a "Printer" module that should support printing on a desktop, but ignore any calls to print on mobile:

Base class

```
export class Printer {
    print(text) {
        throw "unsupported."
    }
}
```

Desktop class

```
import { Printer } from '../printer.js';
export class PrinterDesktop extends Printer {
    print(text) {
        console.log(text);
    }
}
```

Mobile class

```
import { Printer } from '../printer.js';
export class PrinterMobile extends Printer {
    print(text) {
        //do nothing on mobile
    }
}
```

And then if I have a print client module that shouldn't know which Printer implementation is being used:

```
//what would get imported here as 'printer'?
class PrintClient {
    printer.print('hello.');
}
```

In my setup, the desktop bundle would import the PrintClient and the PrinterDesktop class, so it's aware of which one is in use, but the PrintClient isn't aware. I could manually set the Printer in the PrintClient in a constructor or a setter method, but I've got a lot of these objects and that seems like a tedious way to organize these.

Obviously importing any individual class won't work, as the behavior won't vary across devices.

I've looked online and while this seems like it must be a common issue, I haven't found any solutions (maybe I don't know the correct term for what I'm trying to do?)

Any help would be appreciated.